# Is sending UTF-8 encoded characters Network Safe?

Tags: java, networking, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

The reason for encoding with standard Base64 format is to make sure it won't contain any control characters which may be considered as control characters over network. This ensures receiving same data over the other side of the network transfer.

In this scenario, Does UTF-8 character encoding provides same as Base64 by not giving any control characters in the output so that we can send it via network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason for encoding with standard Base64 format is to make sure it won't contain any control characters which may be considered as control characters over network.

**The above statement is incorrect.** Base64 is used *specifically* to encode binary data using 64 of the printable ASCII characters. It is only necessary in specific situations where you are embedding binary data in a protocol which was designed to transfer text (such as embedding attachments in email); it is not required in general for transmitting data over a network. HTTP, for instance, manages perfectly well without it.

> In this scenario, Does UTF-8 character encoding provides same as Base64 by not giving any control characters in the output so that we can send it via network?

No. UTF-8 is a Unicode string format. It cannot be used to encode arbitrary binary data.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Here i'm considering transmitting byte sequences over network. So said if sent as same stream of bytes, many chances for the data containing some control characters which could be wrongly interpreted on receiving end of other side of the network. So Base64 comes to the rescue. Do you still see something i'm missing here still?

Comment: What makes you think that these characters will be "wrongly interpreted"? Unless there is some network protocol involved which you haven't mentioned, the only thing doing the interpretation will be your application. The network itself doesn't care what's in your data.

Comment: You made it clear!  Thanks :) . When sent byte steam as a string and read it back on the other end, Yes "Our Application" does wrong interpretation. Thanks for your question. It clarified. I was in the thought that, Network protocols consider the control characters in the data we sent.

Answer (score 1):

Control characters (0-31 in ASCII) are not touched by UTF-8 encoding and therefore if your protocol cannot transmit them safely you wouldn't solve the issue by using UTF-8.

UTF-8 is about encoding unicode **text** into a 8-bit bytes stream, not about escaping control characters. It solves a different problem.

Note that the input for UTF-8 encoding is **unicode text**, not random bytes: for example it's not possible to encode the byte `0x83` with UTF-8: what you can do is convert the greek letter `"Δ"` encoded in cp737 as `0x83` into UTF-8, or you can encode the russian letter `"Ѓ"` encoded in cp855 as `0x83` into UTF8, but the result would be different ("Δ" is `0xCE+0x94`, while "Ѓ" is `0xD0+0x83`).

Comment: Could also add that UTF-8 it is not about encoding arbitrary binary data either.

Comment: ok I see UTF-8 cant convert back some byte sequences, so in this case, this can't be used. Right?

Comment: @Ayyappa: UTF-8 encoding input is text, not bytes. See edited answer... you cannot encode the byte 0x83 with UTF-8 you can encode "Δ" or "Ѓ".